# Liquibase duplicate changeSet not failing as expected

Tags: oracle, duplicates, liquibase, changeset

So I have an Oracle database which I am updating in liquibase...  in the process of testing my DB build system, I created a new change which is identical in content to an older change with a different ID.  Both are adding a column with the same name,  using SQL.  I would expect the 2nd to fail, since it would attempt to create a column which already exists, but the liquibase command updateTestingRollback reports:

```
Liquibase 'updateTestingRollback' Successful
```

Any ideas what the potential cause may be?

```
<changeSet id="2" author="anonymous" failOnError="true">
  <sql>ALTER TABLE person ADD (col_a VARCHAR(1));</sql>
  <rollback>ALTER TABLE person DROP COLUMN col_a;</rollback>
</changeSet>
<changeSet id="3" author="anonymous" failOnError="true">
  <sql>ALTER TABLE person ADD (col_a VARCHAR(1));</sql>
  <rollback>ALTER TABLE person DROP COLUMN col_a;</rollback>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try running with the `--logLevel=debug` flag added to make sure, but my guess is that oracle is not returning an error code when the sql for the second change is applied. if you use the `<sql>` tag rather than more specific change type tags (i.e. the `<addColumn>` tag), liquibase has a more difficult time detecting problems.